# How to prove that there exist $a$ and $b$ in [0,1] such that $\left| f\left( a \right) +g\left( b \right) -ab \right| \ge \frac { 1 }{ 4 } $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-analysis, functions

Let $f$ and $g$ be any real-valued functions defined on [0,1],Prove that there exist $a$ and $b$ in [0,1]

such that

$$\left| f\left( a \right) +g\left( b \right) -ab \right| \ge \frac { 1 }{ 4 }  $$

- I don't know how can I start with this question. So , I need some hints which can help me to approach this problem .

Comment: Isn't there any additional constrains? Now it is possible to define $f=g=\frac{ab}{2}\to \left| f\left( a \right) +g\left( b \right) -ab \right| =0$

Comment: Unfortunately , there are no additional constrains .

Comment: @KostiantynLapchevskyi: You can't define $f,g$ like that. They are each functions of a single variable.

Comment: @copper.hat oh, I see, it makes sence then

Answer (score 5):

Let us prove it from contradiction.

Suppose that there exist such $f$ and $g$, that 
$$
\left| f\left( a \right) +g\left( b \right) -ab \right| < \frac { 1 }{ 4 }
$$
Consider endpoint of $a$ and $b$, which leads to the following system of inequalities:
$$
-\frac{1}{4}<f(0)+g(0)-0<\frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{1}{4}<f(1)+g(0)-0<\frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{1}{4}<f(0)+g(1)-0<\frac{1}{4}\\
-\frac{1}{4}<f(1)+g(1)-1<\frac{1}{4}
$$
Add 2nd and 3rd inequalities, subtract from them 1st:
$$
-\frac{3}{4}<f(1)+g(1)<\frac{3}{4}
$$
While 4th implies:
$$
\frac{3}{4}<f(1)+g(1)<\frac{5}{4}
$$
Hence, no $f$ and $g$ satisfying initial equation exist. QED.

Comment: Another way of expressing same: Let $\phi(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)-xy$, then $\phi(0,0)+\phi(1,1)-\phi(0,1)-\phi(1,0) = 1$ and hence at least one of the terms must have absolute value no less than ${ 1\over 4}$.